# MSMQ Transaction Commit, Abort, or Dispose?

Tags: c#, msmq

We have a MSMQ that handles various emails and methods based on Case statements.  If a message comes in that doesn't match one of the Cases, it sends out an error email, which is correct.  The problem is that the message stays in the Queue until it works correctly, but because it will never match, it sends the email repeatedly, potentially thousands of times if we don't catch it right away.

I've found that the Transaction is Committed if it does find the Case, but for this error, should it also be Committed, or should it be Aborted or Disposed instead?

Answer (score 1):

It should be Committed because you have received and processed the message, and just because the message didn't conform to the cases, it still performed an action and was processed, meaning it should be removed from the queue via a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I would update your code to trap the unhandled format (is that the default case) and just commit the message, because in reality it has been handled.   In other systems you'd move the message into a dead letter queue instead of the email / as well as.  That allows you to move it back into the queue to be processed if / when you resolve the issue causing the problem.  But in that scenario you'd want to commit the message too.

You don't want to use abort, because that will put it back into the queue.